# How to add NanoSpell to CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to integrate NanoSpell into CKEditor but it does not work for me and I have no idea why... I followed the instructions but it's seems like it's not registering the plugin.

You may download my code from here (Google Drive):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Cc00_51F-aNlFTZ3RlNDVMQm8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add spell checker in CK editor just add below lines in config.js of your CKEDTIOR
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
    config.removePlugins = 'scayt,menubutton,contextmenu';

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried what you suggested but it did not work for me.